# Mocking httpclient json data for offline dev environment

Tags: angular, mocking, angular5

there are quite a few howto's on unit testing and mocking in angular but all of them are for **unit testing**

i need an offline development mode where the http requests are fed from constant json, how can this be done in angular5 ?

Comment: Why don't you just start the server on your own machine?

Comment: @JBNizet because its a complex server.

Comment: Sure, but you could start a simpler one, serving constant json.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mock service that you can substitute at build time:

**db.json**

```
{
   "model": [
       ...
    ]
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
var db = require('./db.json');

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor() {

    }

    getData(): Observable<Model> {
        return Observable.of(db.model);
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying to find a way to do this without replacing the entire service

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import JSON the ES6 way :

Start by adding a definition in your `typings.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Then, you can import your JSON like so :

```
import * as MOCKED_DATA from './mocked-data.json';
```

Comment: i need a way to mock the httpclient response, without changing the service logic.

Comment: Oh well, you have several options : first, an interceptor that will replace your data with your mock. Second, another method, same name + "mock". Third option, `return Observable.of(mock)` instead of you current http call. And why would you not change your service logic ? By definition, if you want to mock, you have to change the logic ...

Comment: interceptor sounds interesting, but i cant find a work example for using it to mock data

Comment: Because no one would do that actually. You will have to do it yourself ! Oh last solution, you too have the XHRBackEnd class, used in tests, to mock a backend and simulate http calls. I've never used it outside of tests, but I guess you could give it a try ...